# jQuery background-image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

My code works perfectly, except for manipulating background images.
I have an images array storing images for each page (only 2 images until I take more, so they duplicate).

For some reason, the images aren't changing when I click...

Also, 'info' is a string containing the name of the page (this is a small portion of my larger script). And the background-colour changing works well, only the image doesn't.

```
$(function () {
var pages = ["home", "about", "portfolio", "misc", "inquire"];

//Finding page corresponding to clicked link
function SetRequest (link, pages)
{
    lookingFor =  ".home";

    for (var i in pages)
    {
        if (link.hasClass(("." + pages[i]).toString()))
        {
            lookingFor = pages[i];
        }
    }

    return lookingFor;
}

//Hiding all other pages, showing page needed
//Also manages hero images/background colours
function ShowCurrentPage (page, pages, lookingFor)
{
    console.log(page, pages, lookingFor);
    if (page.hasClass("." + lookingFor))
    {
        $(".current").animate({opacity: 0}, 600);
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $("." + lookingFor).animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
        $("." + lookingFor).addClass("current");
    }

    SetHeroStuffYo(lookingFor);
}

function SetHeroStuffYo (info) {
    images = ['../images/index/hero-image.png', '../images/hero/car.jpg'];

    if (info == "home")
    {
        $("#hero-bg").css({'background-image' : 'url(' + images[0] + ')'});
        $("#heroColour").css({'background-color' : 'black', opacity : 0});
    }
    else if (info == "about")
    {
        $("#hero-bg").css({'background-image' : 'url(' + images[1] + ')'});
        $("#heroColour").css({'background-color' : 'red', opacity : 0.2});
    }
    else if (info == "portfolio")
    {
        $("#hero-bg").css({'background-image' : 'url(' + images[0] + ')'});
        $("#heroColour").css({'background-color' : 'lightgreen', opacity : 0.2});
    }
    else if (info == "misc")
    {
        $("#hero-bg").css({'background-image' : 'url(' + images[1] + ')'});
        $("#heroColour").css({'background-color' : 'cyan', opacity : 0.2});
    }
    else if (info == "inquire")
    {
        $("#hero-bg").css({'background-image' : 'url(' + images[0] + ')'});
        $("#heroColour").css({'background-color' : 'yellow', opacity : 0.2});
    }
}

$(".nav-link a").click(function(){
    ShowCurrentPage($(this), pages, SetRequest($(this), pages));
});});
```

Comment: does the `hero-bg`'s backgrund-image changed in browser's dom inspector? Maybe it is because the relative url, `var images = ['images/index/hero-image.png', 'images/hero/car.jpg'];`?

Comment: Can you check if images are in correct location ? try giving absolute path to the image

Comment: all images are in the correct locations, and I've tried doing absolute paths...

Comment: `console.log()` the image in each case

Comment: images ARE switching now, just not displaying for some odd reason, they are all the same size as well (which is weird)...

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser tools to check that the css style is actually added (it will be in the style attribute). Then use the browser tools to make sure there's no error in finding the image (like a 404 not found error). The difference in URLs from a CSS file (which are relative to the CSS file itself) and CSS added with JS (which will be relative from the page itself) could be a cause.

I don't see any obvious code syntax errors or anything, so aside from those things to check we'd probably need, at very least, more code (such as seeing the markup) and it would be especially helpful if you could give us a link to somewhere that actually replicates the problem.

Comment: ^^was selecting wrong element (typical), image IS changing. just not displaying...